# Is it possible to draw a box into a video with the position specified for every single frame?

Tags: ffmpeg

With [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46999303/340947) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17354683/340947) I know that it's possible to set filters that draw something on specific frames or with some simple function of the frame number, but what if I have a lookup table for x and y positions (and width and height) of a box I want to draw, one set for each frame?

Comment: quick update: huge chains of `drawbox` with the `enable` property do the trick. you can use that to put boxes anywhere you want on any frames you want.

Answer (score 1):

Drawbox filter can accept all options as [commands](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Commands-82), so you could send these parameters to the filter with frame times, either with some pre-computed [sendcmd](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sendcmd_002c-asendcmd) filter, or from externally using the [zmq](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zmq_002c-azmq) filter.